# <meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=edge”> is not working with IE9

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, microsoft-edge

Every time when I open a page that has the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">`, the page stops suddenly and It says that the page is not responding, do you know an alternative way to turn the compability mode OFF in the pages that I can Use from IE6 to IE10?

Comment: Check your quote marks, the ones here are unicode characters. `“` and `”` should be `"`.

Comment: In my  page they are like that, and it works perfectly in all versions except IE9.

Comment: Not sure which "that" you are referring to, but the unicode characters are wrong, and the browser can do anything it wants with them because they are invalid.

Comment: As for alternatives, you could set X-UA-Compatible via HTTP header.

Comment: I will check it out, I'm kind of stuck on it

Comment: This shouldn't cause IE 9 to freeze. Can you produce a simple document with the `x-ua-compatible` meta tag, and an empty `<head>` and `<body>`, to see if it causes issues in IE 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i hope it help you

```html
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->


    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience IE9 is tricky - it falls between 7/8 which you can deal with and IE10 which is tons better.

This has always worked for me with IE 7-11:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<head>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7">
<![endif]-->
```

Hope this helps...